# How can I export function in a function in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning bash. And I would like to make a function which wrap another function in a temporal script file and execute it with sudo -u command in sub-shell.
 The problem I encountered is the generated script cannot find the wrapped function although it is exported in the wrap function.
 I append test cords below. Someone who finds problems, please let me know. Thank you very much.

main.sh

```
source "./display.sh"
source "./sudo_wrap.sh"

display_func "load success"

sudo_wrap_func '' 'display_func' '3' '4 5'
```

output, display.sh, sudo_wrap.sh and generated temporal file are appended below,

output

```
display_func : load success
export -f display_func
30481: line 5: display_func: command not found
```

display.sh

```
function display_func() {
  echo "display_func : $@"
}
```

sudo_wrap.sh

```
function sudo_wrap_func() {

  local sudo_user="${1:-root}"
  local function_name="${2:?'function_name is null string.'}"
  shift 2
  local func_augs=( "$@" )

  local script

  # *** script : header ***
  script="#!/bin/bash\n"
  script="${script}\n"

  # *** script : making augments for function ***  
  script="${script}augs=("

  for aug in "${func_augs[@]}"
  do
    if [[ "${aug}" =~ [[:blank:]] ]]; then
      script=" ${script} \"${aug}\""
    else
      script=" ${script} ${aug}"
    fi
  done
  script="${script})\n"

  local tmp_script_file="${RANDOM}"

  echo -e "${script}" >> "${tmp_script_file}"

  # *** script : calling function with augments ***  

  echo -e "${function_name} \"\${augs[@]}\"\n" >> "${tmp_script_file}"

  echo "export -f "${function_name}"" >&2
  export -f "${function_name}"

  sudo -u"${sudo_user}" bash "${tmp_script_file}"
  rm "${tmp_script_file}"

}
```

temporally generated file (in this case, file name is 30481)

```
  #!/bin/bash

augs=( 3 "4 5")

display_func "${augs[@]}"
```

Comment: Looks fairly complicated. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Check the `tempfile` command to guard against a temp race.

Comment: @Robert : thank you for commenting. What I want to do is run a function with sudo command. I cannot run sudo some_function. So I wrap the function in another script and run it with sudo command. By the way, what is 'temp race'? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't run a function with `sudo`; run `sudo` from *inside* the function if necessary.

Comment: The temporary file doesn't define the function (`display_func` in this case), it just tries to use it. Note that exporting the function doesn't help, because `sudo` resets the environment before spawning the root process (although `sudo -E` preserves the environment *if* it's explicitly allowed in /etc/sudoers).

Comment: @chepner : thank you for commenting. I have a function which runs a command without sudo. Now I would like to run it as another user. I hope I don't modify the original function. That is the reason I try to wrap the function and run it in sub-shell. If you don't mind, could you tell me why the function cannot find the exported function above?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : thank you for answering. I did not know sudo reset the environment. Thank you again.

Comment: @chepner : Gordon Davisson answered my question. I let you know it in case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, the basic problem is that `sudo` cleans its environment (including both variables and functions) before running the command (/script) as another user. This can be overridden with `sudo -E`, but *only if* it's explicitly allowed in /etc/sudoers.

But the problem is not insoluble; you just have to include the definition of the function in the script, so it gets recreated in that environment. bash even has a convenient command, `declare -f display_func`, that prints the function definition in the appropriate form (and `declare -p variable` does the same for variables). So you can use those to add the appropriate definitions to the script.

Here's a script I wrote to do this. I made a few other changes vs. your script: I take `-u username` to specify a different user to run as (so you don't have to pass `''` as the first argument if you don't want to specify a different user). I also added `-f functionname` and `-v variablename` to "export" additional function and variable definitions into the script (in case the main function depends on them). I also create the temp script file in /tmp, and change ownership if necessary so it'll be readable by the other user.

```
#!/bin/bash

me="$(basename "$0")"
usage() {
    echo "Usage: $me [-u user] [-f otherfunction] [-v variablename] function [args...]" >&2
}

tmp_script_file=$(mktemp "/tmp/${me}.XXXXXXXXXXXX") || {
    echo "Error creating temporary script file" >&2
    exit 1
}
echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$tmp_script_file" # Not actually needed, since we'll run it with "bash"

# Parse the command options; "-u" gets stored for later, but "-f" and "-v" write
# the relevant declarations to the script file as we go.
sudo_user=""
while getopts u:f:v: OPT; do
    case "$OPT" in
      u)
        sudo_user="$OPTARG" ;;

      f)
        declare -f "$OPTARG" >>"$tmp_script_file" || {
            echo "Error saving definition of function $OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
        } ;;

      v)
        declare -p "$OPTARG" >>"$tmp_script_file" || {
            echo "Error saving definition of variable $OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
        } ;;

      ?) usage; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))

if (( $# == 0 )); then # No actual command specified
    usage
    exit 1
fi

# Write the main function itself into the script
declare -f "$1" >>"$tmp_script_file" || {
    echo "Error saving definition of function $1" >&2
    exit 1
}

# Then the command to run it, with arguments quoted/escaped as
# necessary.
printf "%q " "$@" >>"$tmp_script_file"
# the printf above won't write a newline, so add it by hand
echo >>"$tmp_script_file"

# If the script will run as someone other than root, change ownership of the
# script so the target user can read it
if [[ -n "$sudo_user" ]]; then
    sudo chown "$sudo_user" "$tmp_script_file"
fi

# Now launch the script, suitably sudo'ed
sudo ${sudo_user:+ -u "$sudo_user"} bash "$tmp_script_file"

# Clean up
sudo rm "$tmp_script_file"
```

Here's an example of using it:

```
$ foo() { echo "foo_variable is '$foo_variable'"; }
$ bar() { echo "Running the function bar as $(whoami)"; echo "Arguments: $*"; foo; }
$ export -f foo bar # need to export these so the script can see them
$ export foo_variable='Whee!!!' # ditto
$ # Run the function directly first, so see what it does
$ bar 1 2 3
Running the function bar as gordon
Arguments: 1 2 3
foo_variable is 'Whee!!!'
$ # Now run it as another user with the wrapper script
$ ./sudo_wrap.sh -f foo -v foo_variable -u deenovo bar 1 2 3
Running the function bar as deenovo
Arguments: 1 2 3
foo_variable is 'Whee!!!'
```

Note that you could remove the need to export the functions and variables by either running the script with `source` or making it a function, but doing that would require changes to how `$me` is defined, the `usage` function, replacing all those `exit`s with `returns`, and maybe some other things I haven't thought of.

Comment: Cool. What is the use case for this? Specifically, why do you need to dynamically generate a script? Why not just call an existing script (with or without sudo)?

Comment: @Robert: Scripts are easy to run via sudo; shell functions are not. I don't know what the specific use case is, but it's something that's not possible to do directly.

Comment: @Robert : if you can modify the function by yourself, it may be better to put sudo inside the function without creating another script running in sub-shell as chepner mentioned above. By the way, I am a beginner programmer. So my situation in the view of programming design may not be applied to others.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : thank you for detailed code. It is very educational to me in many points.